# Pandas 0.18 invalid syntax

Tags: python, pandas

Python 3.2 installed in virtual environment (named test3) under Linux Debian 7, pandas 0.18 installed with pip in this environment. Test program:

```
import pandas as pd
print('Pandas version ' + pd.__version__)
```

results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pandatest.py", line 1, in <module>
import pandas as pd
File "/home/tad/Programming/testpanda/test3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
from pandas.io.api import *
File "/home/tad/Programming/testpanda/test3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pandas/io/api.py", line 17, in <module>
from pandas.io.packers import read_msgpack, to_msgpack
File "/home/tad/Programming/testpanda/test3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pandas/io/packers.py", line 258
if compress == u'zlib':
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What could be the reason for that? It seems that nobody has reported it before, could not find anything on the web.

Comment: pandas 0.18 doesn't support python 3.2 or 3.3. Only python 2.7, and 3.4 or higher are supported

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should have read release notes first. Silly me...

Comment: Since there is no actual answer given, or clarification about the underlying issue: Python 3.3 re-introduced the [unicode prefix](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/).